# Is there a way to limit the range of the range pattern in awk?

Tags: awk

I am trying to use the `awk` range pattern to find all SQL `select` statements in a group of files, inspired by [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3717989/854151).

From the `awk` manual:

> The `pattern1, pattern2` form of an expression is called a *range pattern*.  It matches all input records starting with a record that matches `pattern1`, and continuing until a record that matches  `pattern2`,  inclusive.

My initial attempt was

```
awk '/select/,/from/' *
```

where `*` in this case just represents a large number of varied files.

This returned several false hits on HTML `select` tags, so I refined my command to

```
awk '/[^<]select[^>]/,/from/' *
```

which seems to have eliminated most of those hits.

However, I still get some false hits from occurrences of the word "select" in a comment, and those hits produce very many lines of noise each before they eventually hit a "from" or the end of the file.
What I would like is for the range pattern not to register a match if there are more than, say, 10 lines between the "select" and the "from".

My question is: Can I make the range pattern fail to match if the number of lines between the match of `pattern1` and the match of `pattern2` exceeds a given threshold, and if so, how?

Comment: To address your "false hits for 'select' in comments" issue you'd have to refine your pattern. I suppose 'select' is at the beginning of the line (with optional whitespace)? - Then a pattern range `/^[[:space:]]*select/,/from/` should help. (You probably need a refinement like that for the `/from/` part as well.)

Comment: @Janis: I would, except I want to match _all_ the `select` statements in all the files given, and there is no guarantee that they all conform to such conventions. It is highly possible that a few statements start after some other non-SQL code on a line.

Comment: But then there would be some syntactical delimiter (like a semicolon), wouldn't it? - So I'd expect you could likely match something like `/(^|;)[[:space:]]*select/,/from/` then.

Answer (score 1):

Range patterns are useful but not flexible. Instead of using them, maintain the between-or-not state in a variable. The awk script `/select/,/from/` is equivalent to

```
/select/ {printing = 1}
printing {print}
/from/ {printing = 0}
```

If you want to limit the range to a number of lines, maintain a counter of lines seen and accumulate the output until you've decided whether to display it.

```
/select/ {select_text = $0; select_line_count = 1;}
select_line_count {select_text = select_text "\n" $0}
/from/ {if (select_line_count <= 10) {print select_text; print}
        select_line_count = 0}
```

You'll probably want to refine the pattern, for example to require that `select` is at the beginning of the line except for whitespace, and is followed by whitespace: `/^[\t ]*select($|[\t ])/`

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the `/pattern1/,/pattern2/` condition as much as you want, by adding a `{}` block after to be performed when this occurs:

See for example how we print those numbers being between 50 and 70, but just the first 5 matches of each block:

```
$ seq 200 | awk '/50/,/70/ {if ($0~/50/) {c=0}; if (c++ <= 5) print}'
50
51
52
53
54
55
150
151
152
153
154
155
```

In your case, you may want to say something like this, that will print the first 10 lines that were matched.

```
awk '/[^<]select[^>]/,/from/ {if (c++ <= 10) print}' *
```

A more complex solution would consist in storing all this output and then printing it at the `END` block. This way, you can control the block itself instead of just a specific line. I would do this storing the data in an array, etc.

Comment: More simply `seq 200 | awk '/50/{c=0}/50/,/70/ || c++==5'`

Comment: Cool, it works! But I don't understand how this `|| c++==5` works and to "what" it is doing the "or" operation. Could you expand it?

Comment: `c++==...` is equal `c==... ; c=c+1`. `/70/` is equal `$0 ~ /70/`. So after `,` we will have `if`pattern `$0 ~ /70/ OR c == 5` with `then add 1 to c `

Comment: @fedorqui: Thank you, this is useful, but not exactly what I'm looking for. For a limit of 10, this will print 10 lines of noise if no match is found for `pattern2`, as opposed to no lines printed which I would prefer.

I am a novice at `awk`, so there is probably a way to buffer the lines from the match of `pattern1` until either reaching a match of `pattern2` and outputting them all, or exceeding the line threshold and discarding all the lines of that failed match. However, I do not yet know enough `awk` to express that.

Comment: @Costas: Thank you for the improvement to @fedorqui's suggestion. I don't quite understand what is happening in the `pattern1` of your range pattern, i.e. `/50/{c=0}/50/`. Why is `/50/` specified twice? Is it valid to write an action in between two regular expression patterns?

Comment: @AndersRaboThorbeck There is not range pattern, but there are command *reset counter **c** when met pattern1* and *pattern1* which belong to second command.